# Spark with docker swarm: Illegal character in hostname

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a Spark and a hadoop cluster which were built with docker swarm. They are identified under the same network. I write a simple WordCount example with Scala:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://10.0.3.16:8088/Sample.txt")

val counts = data.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.foreach(println)
```

When I run the code in master node container of spark, the IP address changes with the name of the container and occurs an error

> Illegal character in hostname at index 12: hdfs://spark_namenode.1.ywlf9yx9hcm4duhxnywn91i35.spark_overlay:9000

and I can not change the container name because it is not allowed in docker swarm.

Comment: I solve the problem, I update core-site.xml as below

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>